# TextfieldShouldReturn breakpoint not being visited after return key hit

Tags: iphone

In the .h

```
@interface WordListTableController : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

In the .m

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    UITextField *FirstField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 130, 25)];
    FirstField.delegate = self;
    FirstField.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:FirstField];
    FirstField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
    [FirstField release];

    return cell;
}

// Handle any actions, after the return/next/done button is pressed
- (BOOL)textfieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textfield 
{
    [textfield resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

What am I missing? Breakpoint is not being visited?

Comment: By the way it did not appear for some reason, but yes I do have <UITextFieldDelegate> after UITableViewController,

Answer (score 1):

The way you are adding the UITextField is problematic. You add it each time cellForRowAtIndexPath is called without ever removing it. So you might actually end up with several text fields stacked on top of each other. 
Try moving *FirstField*'s creation in the `if (cell == nil) {}` block. Maybe this will also solve your problem.

Comment: I changed it to the if (cell == nil) {} block, but it did not trigger the textFieldShouldReturn method? Not sure as to whats happening?

Comment: Ok, I think I see the problem - you have mistyped the method name - it's actually `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField`  (note the capital F in textFieldShouldReturn: )

Comment: OMG, Radu you hit it!!!! I can't believe it, that was the issue! Man, you got it.  Thank you, I was already doubting the whole thing.. thank you.

Comment: 2nd Best Birthday Gift today! Thank you.

Comment: Hey Neil, Please do accept Radu's answer. Your accepting rate is too low.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need repeat create it, just create it while the cell was created!

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    // Configure the cell...
    UITextField *FirstField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 130, 25)];
    FirstField.delegate = self;
    FirstField.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:FirstField];
    FirstField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
    [FirstField release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code snippet. **textfieldShouldReturn** is wrong.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```